# jquery/javascript hide all children form elements except the clicked item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have quite a bit of html code generated from a json schema library I am using.

I have created a jsfiddle out of it here:

Updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39070/

Basically each of the form groups are defined by an html5 attribute :

> div data-schemaid

As you can see from the jsfiddle, all the form div elements are nested under:

```
<div data-schemaid="/properties/TLRoot">
</div>
```

Now, when someone clicks an item on the menu bar, it should hide all the form group items except the one clicked.

I have tried the following code, but that doesnt seem to work.

```
   $(document).on("click","#card-range",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //history.pushState({}, "", this.href);
$('[data-schemaid="/properties/TLRoot/"]').not($('[data-schemaid="/properties/TLRoot/properties/CardRangeList"]')).hide();
    });

    $(document).on("click","#hosts",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('div[data-schemaid="/properties/TLRoot/"]').not($('div[data-schemaid="/properties/TLRoot/properties/HostList"]')).hide();
    });
```

Also, once i have this working it will be cool to have a generic function as opposed to repeating this code for every menu bar item

Comment: If the links are not dynamically inserted you do not need to delegate the click - you can hide div.row>div

Comment: First, [fix your html](http://validator.w3.org). It's not valid and it seems that you have a serious case of ["div-itis".](https://csscreator.com/divitis)

Comment: apologies, the html generated is far more than what I pasted in jsfiddle. While reducing the code, looks like I missed lot of closing div tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is quite long for relatively little content. Also, some menu items have collapse/expand behaviour, so clicking them will then have two effects (the collapse/expand, and the hide/show of the sub-form).

Anyway, here is how you could make it work:

```
// map the menu item with the section that needs to be shown
var dataForId = {
    "card-range": 'div[data-schemaid="/properties/TLRoot/properties/CardRangeList"]',
    "hosts": 'div[data-schemaid="/properties/TLRoot/properties/HostList"]'
    // extend as needed ...
};
// Extract the keys from the above object, and turn that into a selector
var selector = $.map(dataForId, function (value, key) {
    return '#' + key;
}).join(',');

$(document).on("click",selector,function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Hide all relevant sections. Due to the unnecessary nesting and lack of 
    //    useful things to select by, this is quite delicate code -- 
    //    meaning a slight change in the HTML could break this selector:
    $('div[data-schemaid="/properties/TLRoot"]>.well>div>div>.row>[data-schemaid]').hide();
    // Show only the one we need to have
    $(dataForId[this.id]).show();
});
```

See the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39071/)